# Parse XML and set data to Model class

Tags: java, php, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing, domparser

I have an XML below file to parse:

```
<API version="1.0">
<response>
<operation name="GET_REQUEST">
<result>
<statuscode>200</statuscode>
<status>Success</status>
<message>Request details fetched successfully.</message>
</result>
<Details>
<parameter>
<name>id</name>
<value>53481</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>requester</name>
<value>controlm</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>createdby</name>
<value>controlm</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>createdtime</name>
<value>1301369106124</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>duebytime</name>
<value>1302017399984</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>responseduebytime</name>
<value>-1</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>fr_duetime</name>
<value>-1</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>respondedtime</name>
<value>0</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>resolvedtime</name>
<value>0</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>completedtime</name>
<value>1301975054764</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>shortdescription</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>timespentonreq</name>
<value>0hrs 0min</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>subject</name>
<value>PISSUPP IP-SUPP 26834 IP3STG167 OVERRUNNING - IMM</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>requesttemplate</name>
<value>Control-M</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>mode</name>
<value>Auto Ticketing</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>sla</name>
<value>P3 SLA</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>ASSET</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>DEPARTMENT</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>site</name>
<value>Service Desk</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>category</name>
<value>Infrastructure</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>SUBCATEGORY</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>ITEM</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>technician</name>
<value>rajesh</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>status</name>
<value>6.Closed</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>priority</name>
<value>P3</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>impact</name>
<value>3.Low</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>urgency</name>
<value>1.High</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>REQUESTTYPE</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>CLOSURECODE</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>CLOSURECOMMENTS</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>group</name>
<value>Command Center</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>description</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>control_m</name>
<value>TTD2ETLDC</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>mem_name</name>
<value>CUSTOMER_DERIVED_TEMP2_REP.sh</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>order_id</name>
<value>02kbc</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>job_name</name>
<value>IP3STG167</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>owner</name>
<value>ttdbods</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>status reason</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>Main Service Affected</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>Layer</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>ACC Task</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>No of ACC Task</name>
<value/>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>failedtime</name>
<value>29 Mar 2011, 04:24:39</value>
</parameter>
<Notes URI="http://localhost:8400/sdpapi/request/53481/notes/"/>
<Worklogs URI="http://localhost:8400/sdpapi/request/53481/logs/"/>
</Details>
</operation>
</response>
</API>
```

My requirement is to parse this XML file and set data to pojo class.i.e Each `<parameter>` tag data should be set to pojo class respective field.

```
public class Data {
    private int id;
    private String requester;
    private String createdby;
    private String createdtime;
    private String duebytime;
    private String shortdesciption;
    private String timespentonreq;
    private String subject;

    etc..fields..........

    //setters and getters


}
```

Here the code to print each value:

```
Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    xmlData.getBytes("utf-8"))));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("parameter");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodes.item(i);

                Element eElement = (Element) node;

                String ticketDetails = getTagValue("value", eElement);

                if (ticketDetails != null) {

                    System.out.println("ticketDetails : "
                            + getTagValue("value", eElement));

                }

            }
private static String getTagValue(String tag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();

    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
    if (nValue == null)
        return "No Value";
    return nValue.getNodeValue();
}
```

I Have used DOM XmL Parser in this  [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) .Using this I am able to parse and print the data. But I'm not able to set data to individual fields.
Could any one help?

Comment: Post the code where you parsed the file and printed the data.

Comment: You would need a xml parser

Comment: As i see each parameters name,value pair. You should read each name and set value for Data object.

Comment: Could you please provide sample code

Comment: @YuvaRaj Could you please check the code

Comment: Here is some example lets check it > http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is to use SAX parser. Its 3 times efficient than DOM parser.  For it we have to create a handler class and extend DefaultHandler. SAXParser parses the XML file sequentially.  You have to override three methods:

startElement- This method is called when SAXParser gets the start tag in XML

characters - This method is called when SAXParser gets the content in between the tags in XML. But if the contents of the tag is large then it might call it more than ones and each time it has part of that content. Thats the reason i have used StringBuilder in the sample code below. And make sure you delete the contents of the StringBuilder object in the endElement methods once it is used.

endElement -This method is called when SAXParser gets the end tag in XML

See the sample code below. I have typed it in editor but have not tested it. May be it would have compile time errors. but mostly its correct. Have also added the main method where I have added code to call the handler class and parse the XML.

```
    public class ParameterHandler extends DefaultHandler {
 private Data data = null;
 private StringBuilder contentsOfTheCurrentTag=null;
 private Parameter parameter = null;

 public ParameterHandler(){
        contentsOfTheCurrentTag =new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Details")) {
            data=new Data();            
        }
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Parameter")) {
            parameter=new Parameter();          
        }


    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qName) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);
        int length = contentsOfTheCurrentTag.length();
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            parameter.setName(contentsOfTheCurrentTag.toString().trim());
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("value")) {
            parameter.setValue(contentsOfTheCurrentTag.toString().trim());
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("parameter")) {
            if("id".equals(parameter.getName())){
                data.setId(parameter.getValue())
            }
            else if("requester".equals(parameter.getName())){
                data.setRequester(parameter.getValue())
            }
            .
            .so On...
        }
        contentsOfTheCurrentTag.delete(0,length);

    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
         contentsOfTheCurrentTag.append(ch, start, length); 
    }



    //Add getter setter for data
}



public class ReadXMLFile {

   public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
    PremiumHandler handler= new PremiumHandler();
    saxParser.parse("c:\\file.xml", handler);
    Data data=handler.getData();

     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
}
```

Let me know if you have problem using it.

Comment: Hi Sahil Amar,Thanks for reply.After Storing data into ParameterList.should I need to loop the list and set the individual data to Model class(Data)?

Comment: for(int i=0;i<parameterList.size(); i++){
     
      System.out.println(parameterList.get(i).getValue());

                 data.setId(parameterList.get(0).getValue());
      data.setLog(parameterList.get(1).getValue());
                data.setName(parameterList.get(2).getValue());
                 //etc.....fields
      
     }

Comment: See i have edited the sample code. Now there is no need of list. It directly sets to model class

Answer (score 1):

You can use such type of constructions

```
$attribute = "attr";
$model->$attribute_name = $value; // that work as $model->attr = $value
```